# I want my return from SQL to display in a message box in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I made a function so I wont need to do so much coding on my C#
but i am having trouble in displaying the return in a messagebox.
I have tried something and it runs the query perfectly but it does not shows the return in a messagebox.How can I fix or do this?. Please be simple I am still learning.

This is my function and it works fine.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT username,PASSWORD FROM users WHERE username=nim AND PASSWORD=fass)THEN

SET @userID=(SELECT  userID FROM users WHERE username=nim AND PASSWORD=fass);
INSERT INTO TRANSACTION(userID,`transaction`,`date`) VALUES(@userID,"Logged the System",NOW());

SET @MessageResult=(SELECT  CONCAT("Welcome ", username) FROM users WHERE username=nim AND PASSWORD=fass);
RETURN @MessageResult;


ELSE
RETURN "Invalid User Name or Password";
END IF;
```

and here is my code on C#

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string loadstring = @"server=localhost;database=librarys;userid=root;password=1234;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(loadstring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT func_login('" + this.txtusername.Text + "','" + this.txtpassword.Text + "');", conDataBase);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: You're not reading what the query is returning or trying to show it in a message box. Read up on data readers or use `ExecuteScalar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove myReader, and put these two lines

```
        string returnedValue = cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(returnedValue);
```

Comment: thank you so much sir. You made me so happy right now.
I've been trying to make this to work for 3 days.
Its not just me you just helped and they want say thanks to you..

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work.

```
while(myReader.Read())
{
     String res = myReader.GetString(0); 
     MessageBox.Show(res.Message);
}
```